# What is the difference between a cut and a body recomposition?

Tags: weight-loss

So I'm new to this whole fitness thing and have never worked out a day in my life but recently decided I wanted to lose weight and get into shape via calisthenics. For reference, I'm 17, 5'8 and I wish to go from 90kg to 75kg.

I did some research on what would be the best approach and came across cutting and body recomposition and I'm having trouble understanding the difference between the 2 because, as far as I understand and from the videos I've seen, to do a body recomp, you'd have to be in a calorie deficit anyways which means you'd be losing weight so is this not the same as cutting?

Thanks a lot.

(Ps. I'm sorry if this is a dumb questions, I've never done this before)

Answer (score 1):

#### Cutting indicates weight loss, recomposition indicates weight neutral.

Usually. They’re just words for similar ideas and different people may have different understandings of each word. But *generally*, cutting will refer to *cutting weight*, whereas recomposition will refer to *changing body composition without changing body weight*.

The idea here is that cutting weight inevitably leads to some loss in lean mass, though there are ways to attenuate that loss to some extent. A recomposition is an attempt to gain lean mass while losing fat mass, which can be done in some circumstances, but require a very modest calorie deficit, high protein, and a robust resistance training stimulus.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man. I just have 2 questions though. Wouldn't losing muscle mass via a cut be bad since you'd be getting weaker? And, If I were to do a recomp, would it decrease my overall mass or keep it the same but have a higher percentage of it be muscle as oppose to fat?

Comment: @JamesM: It would be bad if it's prolonged, but in reality you don't really lose that much muscle mass in cuts except under extreme circumstances (going extremely aggressively and cutting to very low body fat percentages). Muscle memory also helps you regain the mass faster than it took to get it in the first place. Recomps would decrease your overall mass initially because fat mass has a higher volume than muscle mass (and loses easier than muscle gains), but it can take a really, really long time to see any significant changes.